# Как могу исправить Multiple inheritance from classes 'BaseViewController' and 'PFQueryTableViewController'?

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Подскажите как я могу исправить ошибку?у меня в каждом разделе ViewController унаследуется BaseViewController от менюшки.Как выйти из положения этого? вот мой код : 
Буду благодарен за любую мельчайшую помощь!!!

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class SportViewController: BaseViewController, PFQueryTableViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tablView: UITableView!



 func queryForTable()->PFQuery<PFObject> {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "betting")
        query.order(byAscending: "match")
        return query
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
       self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "uklogo.png"))


}

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    }

    func tableView (_tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?)-> PFTableViewCell {
        let cell = tablView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prognozCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
        cell.dataLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "data") as? String
        cell.matchLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "match") as? String
        cell.progLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "prognoz") as? String
        cell.noteText.text = object?.object(forKey: "note") as? String

        let imageFile = object?.object(forKey: "image") as? PFFile

        cell.imagesP.image = UIImage(named: "sport1")
        cell.imagesP.file = imageFile
        cell.imagesP.loadInBackground()




        return cell


    }


    func tableView (_tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAt IndexPath: IndexPath)-> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row + 1 > (self.objects?.count)! {
            return 10
        }


}
    @IBAction func reloadData(_ sender: Any) {
         self.loadObjects()    }

}
```

Comment: ответ на мой вопрос.Нашел на сайте eng.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263359/multiple-inheritance-from-classes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440428/how-can-i-have-a-custom-class-inherit-from-multiple-superclasses?rq=1

Comment: А что у вас в `BaseViewController` добавлено и от кого он наследуется?

Comment: У меня у наследуется addSlideMenuButton.